# Does "associated with" imply a certain hierarchy?

Tags: word-usage

I have two items that bear a certain connection, and I want to describe this connection using the word "associated".

If I want to say that A is associated with B, does this imply that B is greater/more important than A?
Or can I just as well say that B is associated with A?

As an example, I could say:

> I am associated with Company X.

but it seems wrong to say

> Company X is associated with me.

But is it OK to say something like

> I am associated with my team mate

(where the two of us are equals)?

Comment: No. And the dictionary should make this clear. By itself, *associate* suggests a relation; nothing more. The relation could be pretty much *any* relation.

Comment: I don't think to be "associated", one person or entity with another, infers any hierarchical rank. I think the word infers merely the existence of a nexus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

I think there are three scenarios (not considering the 'spend time with' sense of 'associate with'):

(1) **non-commutativity** (ie the order *A is associated with B* is not reversible):

*I am associated with Macrosift.*

(2) **commutativity, both syntactic and semantic**:

*Wealth is associated with freedom.*

(3) **commutativity, syntactic but not semantic**

*Klausenheimer was associated with (involved with ... / instrumental in) the Monhittan project.*
 (Though note that the 'reckoned to be involved in' sense, almost the reverse of the next sense, is an alternative reading here.)
...

*The Monhittan project was associated with (regarded as being the brainchild of) Klausenheimer.*

All these senses are available. If context does not differentiate, a rephrasing is advisable.