# What is the word for the complementary relationship implied by the word dependent?

Tags: synonyms, antonyms, grammatical-roles

Dependency is directional. Starting a car is dependent on petrol. But petrol is not dependent on starting a car.

What word describes the relationship from petrol to the car?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "associated with" imply a certain hierarchy?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349759/does-associated-with-imply-a-certain-hierarchy)

Comment: Related: [Does 'associated with' imply a certain hierarchy?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349759/does-associated-with-imply-a-certain-hierarchy/349772#349772)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**requisite** (n., adj.)

> A necessary or indispensable thing; something needed for a particular
> purpose.
>
> *All the requisites for living are there if you take the time to look.* OED

> ADJECTIVE
> You can use requisite to indicate that something is
> necessary for a particular purpose.
> [formal]
> *She filled in the
> requisite paperwork.*
> Synonyms: necessary, needed, required, called
> for
>
> COUNTABLE NOUN
> A requisite is something that is necessary for a particular purpose
>
> [formal]
> *An understanding of accounting techniques is a requisite for the work of the analysts.* [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/requisite)

If you really need something opposite to *dependency*, **requisiteness** does exist:

> The fact of being requisite; necessity, need.
>
> *Focusing on the preexisting social facticity of possessive
> individualism..and its requisiteness to the functioning of market
> society.* OED

---

> ... and with arguing that certain sorts of relationships are
> 'requisite' in terms of the tasks which have to be achieved. There is
> no systematic evidence in terms of which such claims as to the
> **requisiteness** of the advocated patterns can be tested... [R. K. Brown; *Understanding Industrial Organizations*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Understanding_Industrial_Organizations/FTjfAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=requisiteness&pg=PA60&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

You hinted at one yourself with "directional." The phrase "unidirectional relationship" seems to be used mainly in the fields of computing logic (and apparently [psychology](https://quizlet.com/137291601/aamc-psychology-flash-cards/)?), but has [exactly the definition you give](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/maximo-eam-saas?topic=overview-unidirectional-bidirectional-relationships). For a more informal equivalent, you could just say "one-way relationship."

Comment: This seems to be a comment on the wording of the question, rather than an answer to it.

Comment: Really? Sorry, perhaps I was unclear. "Unidirectional relationship" or "one-way relationship" express what the OP is looking for (to a T, it seems to me).

Comment: The OP was looking for a word that can fill the blank in 'If starting a car is dependent on petrol, then petrol is ____ for starting a car'.

Comment: @jsw29 Sorry, I took it differently. "What word describes the relationship." I take it they're looking for an adjective that modifies the relationship, not the petrol.

Answer (score -1):

1. Mutual dependence. Mutually dependent.
2. Interdependence. Interdependent.